# Call to member function is ambigous when overloading both vector of chars and string c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading

I want to overload a function the following way:

```
void f(string s){
    cout << "String case" << endl;
}

void f(vector<char> v){
    cout << "Vector case" << endl;
}
```

For the case I insert a string object or a vector object, everything is fine:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "hello";
    f(s); // Prints "String case"
    vector<char> v = {'a', 'b'};
    f(v); // Prints "Vector case"
    return 0;
}
```

But if I want to run `f({'a', 'b'});`, since the array can be automatically converted to both a string and a vector, I get `error: call of overloaded ‘f()’ is ambiguous`. Suppose I want to treat this case as a vector, how can I tell the compiler that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a `initializer_list<char>` overload, calling `f` with a brace-initialized list such as `{'a', 'b'}` will select that overload as the best match.

You can just call the `vector<char>` overload explicitly from there.

```
void f(std::initializer_list<char> v) 
{
    f(std::vector<char>{v});  // call the vector version
}
```

and now the following call works as you want.

```
f({'a', 'b'}); // Prints "Vector case"
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8ezW6a).

Note that you should be taking the `string` and `vector<char>` parameters by `const&` in the respective overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Be explicit about which type the braces are being used to initialize:

```cpp
f(string{'a', 'b'});
f(vector<char>{'a', 'b'});
```